# My Draw Method Is Not Working

Tags: c++, sdl

Although there is no problem loading the "Image" my draw function doesn't draw anything. What might be the cause of this?

```
void Draw_InGameMenu()
{
    Rect6.w = 100;
    Rect6.h = 100;
    Rect6.x = 100;
    Rect6.h = 100;

    MenuCaption.x = Rect6.x;
    MenuCaption.y = Rect6.y;

    SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, Image, NULL, &Rect6);

    SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, MenuCaptionTexture, NULL, &MenuCaption);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rect6.y never gets a value assigned to it. That may be the cause of the problem.

Comment: Thanks. I've been staring at the code for half an hour now. :)

Comment: Haha I've had this exactly same typo-induced bug with `SDL_Rect`. Lesson learned: never use one-letter abbreviations as identifiers (`w`, `h`) when there's something more visually distinguishing available (`width`, `height`).